# Avoiding the use of SelectList in the business layer (MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a fairly large MVC 3 application, and I'm running into an issue that doesn't smell quite right to me. This question takes a little set up to understand, so here are the premises that I'm currently operating on:

- Views should be strongly typed (ViewBag/ViewData should be avoided)
- Because the views are strongly typed, view model objects should be created that encapsulate all the data the view needs to display
- When we have a need for drop down menus we should have two properties:

  1. A property in the model that stores the selected value of the drop down
  2. A `SelectList` property in the view model that represents the items in the drop down
- The view itself always uses the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper method
- We are using Entity Framework 4, and letting it generate entity classes from our already designed database
- To avoid duplication and take advantage of LINQ, we are not creating our own separate business/model classes but adding to the partial classes generated by the entity framework
- These partial classes that we write are located in the business layer to make everything compile correctly
- Most model classes have a shared editor template that can be used in multiple views

Here's where the trouble comes in. The shared editor template's model type is set to the model class. This means that the partial view that makes up the editor template does not have access to the containing view model object where the list of drop down items is stored.

I was able to "solve" this by adding a `SelectList` property directly to the model class in the business layer instead of keeping it in the view model. But the `SelectList` class is specific to MVC, which in turn means that my business layer has a dependcy on MVC. That doesn't seem right to me because the BL should be agnostic to the UI.

Has anyone else run into this issue? How should I solve this? It's also possible that one of my premises are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we ended up taking the simple way out. In the business layer we just changed the type to plain old `Object`. I figured that, regardless of the presentation layer, it will need some sort of list to contain the options available.

I know this isn't super clean as per @Darin and @Jakub, but I don't see our end result being any different this way except that we've avoided having to write and/or set up a whole bunch of mappings between objects.

Answer (score 4):

Everything seems very nice and good design up until this point (which is not surprising as it is that point that is causing you headaches :-)):

> Most model classes have a shared editor template that can be used in multiple views

It's view models that should have editor templates and not EF models. And because view models are specific to the requirements of the view you are free to put whatever information you need into them, like in this case the `SelectList`. So don't simply define a *root* view model that has your EF models as properties (that's not a view model). Define a view model that is designed to meet the requirements of the particular view. Don't put a single EF class in your view model hierarchy and you will see how much simpler your life will be :-)

And don't worry if you have duplicate properties in your view models. That's what those classes are designed for. Also [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could greatly simplify the mapping between your models and view models.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I'm still conflicted. If we don't use the model classes at all (not even as properties of the view model) then it seems like we're writing a lot of code that consists only of properties that are already duplicated somewhere else. It also seems like we would be giving up some of the advantages of EF, like its ability to track changes when used with the controllers `UpdateModel` method. We are already using AutoMapper for a few things, so that part's not a big deal.

Comment: @Shea - I don't think track changes for EF entities really works in web scenarios, as you loose the tracking once the response goes to the client.

Comment: See my answer to this question on how we're using it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022943/editing-an-object-in-entity-framework-and-saving-it-to-the-database-in-asp-net-mv/5023147#5023147 . Although I guess if all the property names matches it might still work?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 main solution IMHO:

**1. Generate DTOs / Models for your business logic entities**

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to minimize the copying code. 
You will achieve a nice separation between your view and business logic.
This however may be time-consuming for your large application.

**2. Use extension methods**

Instead of declaring a SelectList property in EF entity partial class and polluting your business logic with view-related code create an extention methods for your EF entites in Web project. You can than move your view-related code to web project from BL and keep type-safety.

*Example:*

Business Logic assembly

```
// This is EF entity
public partial class FooTable
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Web assembly

```
public static class FooTableExtensions
{
    public static SelectList GetSelectList(this IEnumerable<FooTable> fooTables)
    {
        return new SelectList(); // Create your select list from FooTables here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution number 1 is how we originally started developing our app, and we decided that approach wasn't worth the considerable extra effort. It also throws away some of the advantages of using LINQ (such as deferred execution). Do you have any examples of solution number 2? How would that work in practice?